# Можно ли вставить строку в середину таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в БД.
id, name, info, no.
(id - pimary index, auto_increment)
И, допустим, следующие значения:
0, Сергей, слесарь, 1
1, Иван, токарь, 3
3, Алексей, плотник, 7...

Если добавить строчку "2, Федор, админ, 5", то она отображается после всех остальных данных, хотя id соответствует 3-й строке таблицы.

Как впихнуть именно в третью строку (чтоб остальные "съехали" ниже)?

Comment: я имел ввиду именно в PHPmyAdmin...
Так то я знаю, как сортировать, а в админе, даже если вручную id поставить, все-равно сортируется по времени создания)

Но все-равно спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтож вы сразу то не сказали про phpMyAdmin... для сортировки по определенному столбцу достаточно один раз нажать на заголовок столбца в вашем случае "id", тогда записи выстроятся по возрастанию, еще раз нажать и по убыванию.

Comment: Так и делаю. но интересно, почему в Админе сортируется по времени создания строки, хотя ключевой столбец - id...

Comment: Они вообще не сортируются (и наличие первичного ключа тут ни при чем), просто последние добавленные оказываются в хвосте. Если из таблицы, наряду с добавлением новых, будут удаляться записи, то **может** наступить момент, когда вновь добавляемые записи окажутся в середине (или в начале).

Answer (score 2):

Если подойти по честному, то порядок следования записей в таблице не определен. Он появляется только при выводе. Что бы его изменить  - нужно применять сортировку.
В Вашем случае есть поле no. Вставляйте как можете, а при выводе делайте так

```
select * from table_name order by no;
```

И записи будут в том порядке, который хочется.

Не забывайте, что есть такая штука, как автоинкремент. И поле id как раз такое. Поэтому просто так его задать нельзя, оно автоматически само сгенерится. И в Вашем случае скорее всего вставится запись  "4, Федор, админ, 5"

Answer (score 1):

Обычный запрос SELECT никак не может гарантировать верную (для вашего контекста) последовательность вывода записей, данные будут помещены там (при записи), где для них найдется место, и, соответственно, в той же последовательности будут извлекаться. Для правильного (в вашем контексте) вывода воспользуйтесь следующей конструкцией:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY `id`
```

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), насколько я понял проблема как раз в `id`, а не `no`. И несмотря на то, что поле с автоинкрементом, вы можете использовать вставку, задавая значение поля самостоятельно, главное чтобы оно, для данного случая (т.к. PRIMARY), было уникальным. Т.е. использовать конструкции вида:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `info`, `no`) VALUES (2, 'Федор', 'Админ', 5);
```

Или:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `info`, `no`) VALUES ('Федор', 'Админ', 5);
```

Решать только вам.

Comment: лучше не делать программную модификацию автоинкрементного поля. Только в порядке ремонта таблиц.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласитесь, для данного случая, вам ничего более и не остается. Поэтому я позволил себе это подметить. Но с точки зрения логики, вы, конечно, правы.

Answer (score 0):

Выгрузить, удалить таблицу, создать таблицу, занести записи в нужном порядке. После этого без сортировки будет выводить в порядке поступления.