# Изменить значение в записях БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 5 записей в таблице users (sort, name)

```
SORT | NAME

1 Андрей
2 Денис
3 Игорь
4 Максим
5 Сергей
```

Через PHP я их вывожу по порядку (по sort). Но, теперь мне нужно добавить Александра после Игоря. То есть, придётся в дальнейшем добавлять записи МЕЖДУ уже существующими, чтобы они выводились не в конце, а в средине.
Что сделать в таком случае?
Как я понимаю, нужно переопределить sort всех записей, которые будут после Александра?
Получается:
Игорь - 3,
Александр (новая запись) - уже 4,
Максим - уже не 4, а 5,
Сергей - соответственно 6.

Но, как это сделать?
Как изменить sort (на один больше) всех нижеследующих после Александра записей?

Comment: Надо добавить поле `sort`, а `id` не трогать. И вообще - какая разница где и кто?

Comment: Зачем менять id, почему бы не добавить дополнительный столбец, чтобы сортировать по нему и перенумеровывать как угодно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32062/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: Ни в коем случае нельзя путать идентификатор с номером по порядку. Это совершенно разные вещи и между ними нет ничего общего. Соответственно, трогать идентификатор вообще нельзя. Это все равно что дать тебе имя и фамилию одноклассника, чтобы ты стоял на физкультуре позади него.

Comment: Даже если добавить отдельный столбец sort. Как потом изменить sort (на один больше) всех нижеследующих 
после Александра записей?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: `update users set sort = sort + 1 where sort >=5`
В результате выполнения запроса освободится запись у которой sort = 5, и все записи сдвинутся на "1 дальше по списку сортировки"

Comment: На самом деле тут другой вопрос - а почему вам требуется вставлять записи именно __между__ другими записями? Если это какая-то древовидная структура типа начальник-подчиненный то тут другой подход нужен.

Comment: На самом деле, с именами это лишь пример. На самом деле, каждая отдельная запись (имя в примере) - это отдельная текстовая статья с текстом. И вот эти статьи должны выводиться по порядку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
-- раздвигаем
UPDATE users
SET sort = sort + 1
WHERE sort > ( SELECT sort
               FROM users
               WHERE name = 'Игорь' );
-- и вставляем
INSERT INTO users (sort, name)
SELECT sort + 1, 'Александр'
FROM users
WHERE name = 'Игорь';
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста прокомментировать максимально кратко?

Comment: Кратко - первый запрос увеличивает на 1 все номера для записей после Игоря, при этом освобождается одно значение. Именно туда второй запрос пишет новую запись.

Comment: А что означает "SELECT sort + 1, 'Александр'" в запросе добавления новой записи? Какое изначальное значение у sort? Где оно в этом запросе определяется?

Comment: @СергейПлотницкий Ну там же ниже вполне вменяемое условие отбора `WHERE name = 'Игорь'`. Т.е. значение `sort` будет взято из той записи, в которой `name = 'Игорь'`.

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал, что при добавлении записи можно указывать WHERE

Comment: @СергейПлотницкий *не знал, что при добавлении записи можно указывать WHERE* Сфига бы при добавлении? Это чистый SELECT, выборка - просто результат этой выборки используется для добавления.